# TikZ: force two pictures to use the same baseline/frame of reference

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, automata, baseline

I have two TikZ automata I would like to place side-by-side:
[image]

However, I would prefer the 'start' nodes to be aligned vertically on the page. This happens automatically if I add help lines large enough to cover the two figures:
[image]

Here's the code for the lower image; commenting out the help lines yields the upper image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{negative} = [circle, minimum width=8pt, fill, inner sep=0pt]
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=1.4cm,on grid,semithick,inner sep=2pt,bend angle=25]
\draw[help lines] (-1,-1.2) grid (3,2);
\node[initial,negative] (A) {};
\node[negative] (B) [above right=of A] {};
\node[negative,accepting] (C) [below right=of B] {};
\path [every node/.style={font=\footnotesize}]
(A)
edge node {$f$} (B)
edge [swap] node {$h$} (C)
(B)
edge [bend left] node {$m$} (C)
edge [bend right,swap] node {$n$} (C)
;
\end{tikzpicture}%
\qquad%
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=1.4cm,on grid,semithick,inner sep=2pt,bend angle=45]
\draw[help lines] (-1,-1.2) grid (3,2);
\node[initial,negative] (A) {};
\node[negative] (B) [above right=of A] {};
\node[negative,accepting] (C) [below right=of B] {};
\node[negative] (D) [below right=of A] {};
\path [every node/.style={font=\footnotesize}]
(A)
edge node {$f$} (B)
edge [swap] node {$h$} (C)
edge [swap] node {$g$} (D)
(B)
edge node {$n$} (C)
(D)
edge [swap] node {$m$} (C)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How do I get the lower figure, without resorting to the help lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use the `baseline` key in the `tikzpicture` options to specify that each picture should be aligned to the baseline by a particular node name (here I used `(A)`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{negative} = [circle, minimum width=8pt, fill, inner sep=0pt]
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A),->,shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=1.4cm,on grid,semithick,inner sep=2pt,bend angle=25]
\node[initial,negative] (A) {};
\node[negative] (B) [above right=of A] {};
\node[negative,accepting] (C) [below right=of B] {};
\path [every node/.style={font=\footnotesize}]
(A)
edge node {$f$} (B)
edge [swap] node {$h$} (C)
(B)
edge [bend left] node {$m$} (C)
edge [bend right,swap] node {$n$} (C)
;
\end{tikzpicture}%
\qquad%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A),->,shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=1.4cm,on grid,semithick,inner sep=2pt,bend angle=45]
\node[initial,negative] (A) {};
\node[negative] (B) [above right=of A] {};
\node[negative,accepting] (C) [below right=of B] {};
\node[negative] (D) [below right=of A] {};
\path [every node/.style={font=\footnotesize}]
(A)
edge node {$f$} (B)
edge [swap] node {$h$} (C)
edge [swap] node {$g$} (D)
(B)
edge node {$n$} (C)
(D)
edge [swap] node {$m$} (C)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, ok. That looks like a reasonable approach.  Thanks :)

I guess I can also hack 

`\draw[white] (-1,-1.2) grid (3,2);` but that feels wrong...